# Maximum recursion depth while applying a Listing filter in django

Tags: python, django, loops, recursion, filter

I am trying to implement Listing Filter from django filters. First "type" is the attribute that I want my filter to be based inside **models.py** of my app.

```
class detaileditems(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 255)
    type = models.CharField(max_length= 45, null=True)
    pubdate = models.DateTimeField()
    body = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to= 'images/')
```

I have created a separate **filters.py** inside my application where I have called the filters.

```
import django_filters
from .models import detaileditems
class ListingFilters(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = detaileditems
        fields = {'type': ['exact']}
```

Next here is my function inside **views.py** file-

```
from .models import detaileditems
from .filters import ListingFilters
def alldetailed2(request):
    items = detaileditems.objects
    listing_filter = ListingFilters(request.GET, queryset=items)
    context = {
        'listing_filter' : listing_filter,
        'items': items,
    }
    return render(request, 'detailed2/detailed2.html',context)
```

Lastly in my html file "**detailed2.html**" which is inside the application template folder of "detailed2".

```
<div class = "col-lg-6 col-md-8 mx-auto">
    <form method = "get">
            {{ listing_filter.form }}
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" type="submit">Search</button>
         </form>
</div>
<div class = "container">
     <div class = "row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm2 row-cols-md-3 g-3">
          {% for listing in listing_filter.qs %}
          <div class = "col">
               {% include "detailed2/detailed2.html" %}
          </div>
           {% endfor %}
      </div>
</div>
```

I am getting a maximum recursion depth error.

[image: Error]

And here is my folder structure for better understanding.

[image: Folder structure]

Comment: Please don't edit questions in such a way that they invalidate existing answers! [Ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you have a different question. Plus from that edit of yours, why are you confused about that url being rendered over there? That's literally what you rendered: `{% url 'alldetailed2' %}`...

Answer (score 1):

There is an earlier post on maximum recursion depth:
[earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/what-is-the-maximum-recursion-depth-in-python-and-how-to-increase-it)

Sometimes a solution can be found by rethinking the algorithm so it uses iteration over for example a list instead of recursion. I guess you need to convince yourself you are not making an error and then file an issue with Django.

As a quick fix you can try to increase the recursion depth. See post I linked to.

---

I do see a self reference in the html:

'''
{% include "detailed2/detailed2.html" %}
'''

could that be the root cause of your trouble?

Comment: yes the recursion issue is not coming the page is loaded without error, but the search results are not coming? Any idea why?

Comment: Alas, I don't know Django. I had encountered the maximal recursion limit in my own programming, so that is what drew me here.

Comment: This really seems like the problem. You're including the same template inside of the template. That should end up in a problem like this.

Answer (score 0):

In OP's `views.py`, ensure it has `.all()` at the end when OP is getting the items

```
def alldetailed2(request):
    items = detaileditems.objects.all()
    listing_filter = ListingFilters(request.GET, queryset=items)
    context = {
        'listing_filter' : listing_filter,
        'items': items,
    }
    return render(request, 'detailed2/detailed2.html',context)
```

Then one can render in one's template like this

```
{% for detailed_item in listing_filter.qs %}
    <h2>{{ detailed_item.title }}</h2>
    <p>{{ detailed_item.body }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

instead of the

```
{% include "detailed2/detailed2.html" %}
```

---

Keep in mind as well that there are [guidelines in the way one names classes, functions, ...](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/).

Django models should use the `CapWords` convention. Also, it's considered and [anti-pattern to use model classes with a plural name](https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/plural-model-class-names.html). So, `DetailedItem` instead of `detaileditems`.

The functions names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores, like `all_detailed_2` instead of `alldetailed2`.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you missed form action. When there is a keyword entered then form submission should call a same function as you're using for listing all the articles.

```
<form method = "post" action="{% url 'alldetailed2' %}">
            <input type='text' name='articale_name' />
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" type="submit">Search</button>
         </form>
```

in View function:

```
article_name = request.POST.get("articale_name")
if article_name:
    "filter model with article_name"
else:
    list out all the Articles same as earlier
```